# $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k {{m+1}\choose{k}}{{m+n-k}\choose{m}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, induction

I'm supopsed to show that if $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k {{m+1}\choose{k}}{{m+n-k}\choose{m}}
= \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    1 & \quad \text{if $n=0$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{if $n>0$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

I used mathematical induction about $n$, but I couldn't reach at the answer. Also, I tend to make the process to show this type of equality quite non-elegant, so I want a concise solution for this. Since the case of $n=0$ was already proved, you don't need to show it.

Comment: Have you tried a combinatoric proof using the inclusion/exclusion principle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use convolution of generating functions:

Let
\begin{align*}
  a_k &= (-1)^k\, \binom{m+1}{k} \\
  b_k &= \binom{m+k}{m}
\end{align*}

The corresponding g.fs are:
\begin{align*}
  A(x) &= (1-x)^{m+1} \\
  B(x) &= \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}
\end{align*}
Multiplying $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ 
\begin{align*}
  A(x)\cdot B(x) &= \sum_{n\ge 0} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\, b_{n-k}\right) x^n \\
  &= \frac{(1-x)^{m+1}}{(1-x)^{m+1}} \\
  &= 1
\end{align*}

which verifies that the sum is $1$ only when $n=0$

Comment: Thanks! I especially wanted to know a proof using generating function like this one.

Comment: You are welcome!